# gotype command not installed with Go?

Tags: go

i got Go 1.4 / Win32 from offsite. I see foder "c:\go\bin". No `gotype` command in it. I need `gotype` -- where is gotype, how to install it?

Comment: SE is not an alternative to Google. [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Bf5jbJwYXoA/RJxohbcDpbUJ), [link2](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/?repo=tools#hg%2Fcmd%2Fgotype)

Comment: Note: Go 1.5 or 1.6 should introduce "`go doc`". I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update April 2015: Go 1.5 should introduce "`go doc`": see

- [review 9227](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/9227/3): `cmd/go`,`cmd/doc`: add "`go doc`"
- [review 9226](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/9226/): rename `doc.go` to `alldocs.go` in preparation for "`go doc`"

> Add the new `go doc` command to the go command, installed in the tool directory.
>
> usage:

```
go doc [-u] [package|[package.]symbol[.method]]
```

---

Original answer (January 2015)

You would need:

```
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gotype
```

That would install that extra tools from [`golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gotype`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gotype):

> The `gotype` command does syntactic and semantic analysis of Go files and packages like the front-end of a Go compiler.
>   Errors are reported if the analysis fails; otherwise `gotype` is quiet (unless `-v` is set).

---

Note: this isn't the only extra tool you might consider installing, as illustrated in [this article](http://www.goinggo.net/2013_10_01_archive.html):

```
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gotype
go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint
```

---

Note: Go 1.5 will make that operation even faster.
See [commit dc2d64b](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/dc2d64bf81b3342d35bdbfa42b971087ade6dfc6) by [Brad Fitzpatrick (`bradfitz`)](https://github.com/bradfitz):

> ### `cmd/go`: cache results of HTTP requests done during meta tag discovery
>
> Previously, running

```
$ go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

> would results in dozens of HTTP requests for:

```
https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
```

> once per package under `x/tools`.
>
> **Now it caches the results**.
>   We still end up doing one HTTP request for all the packages under `x/tools`, but this reduces the total number of HTTP requests in ~half.

Comment: Also in the GitHub Go repo: https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/cmd/gotype